# double.parse trims decimal 0 at end

Tags: flutter, dart

Actually I was trying to parse string to double with 2 Decimal places. But double.parse trims decimal 0.

eg:-

```
var val = double.parse("32.50");
print(val1); //Expected -> 32.50 Actual - > 32.5
```

Comment: Why would you expect this? `val` is a number and numbers don't have leading zeros before or trailing zeros after the comma. If you need a certain format for your number, convert it to  a string ...

Comment: for double it doesnt matter, if you want again to convert to string, use `.toStringAsFixed`

Comment: 32.5, 32.50, 32.500, 32.5000, 32.50000, 32.50000, etc are all the same double. There is no difference

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
 var val = double.parse("32.50");
 print(val.toStringAsFixed(2));  //output - > 32.50
}
```